# JaVers not creating tables in Oracle 12

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, openshift, javers

in our project we are using JaVers with SpringBoot and FlyWay as database migrate tool. When I build my project locally everything is OK. Flyway clean schema and apply all migrations. When I starting my app Javers is creating his tables etc. Locally I'm using Oracle 11XE

The probleam appears when I try to build project on our CI enviroment - OpenShift + Oracle 12. Everything is OK but JaVers not create tables when application is starting.

When running locally with empty schema in log i can see JaVers DDL, for example:

```
o.p.core.schema.SchemaManagerImpl        : 
creating entity with name jv_commit using ddl:
CREATE TABLE jv_commit (
commit_pk NUMBER NOT NULL,
author VARCHAR2(200),
commit_date TIMESTAMP,
commit_id NUMBER(22,2),
CONSTRAINT jv_commit_pk PRIMARY KEY(commit_pk)
)
```

But when run in CI I see only:

```
org.javers.core.JaversBuilder            : loading GroovyAddOns ...
org.javers.core.JaversBuilder            : loading GuavaAddOns ...
org.javers.core.JaversBuilder            : loading JodaAddOns ...
```

I read something about bad dialect but in my `*.yml` file I have it defined:

```
spring:
  jpa:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

And my JaVers properties:

```
javers:
  algorithm: LEVENSHTEIN_DISTANCE
```

Additionally when I add new script for FlyWay which create JaVers tables everything is OK. My JaVers dependency:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
                <artifactId>javers-core</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.javers</groupId>
                <artifactId>javers-spring-boot-starter-sql</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.3</version>
            </dependency>
```

I'm creating JaVers instance by dependency injection:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class JaVersService {

    @Autowired
    private Javers javers;

    //some logic
}
```

When app is starting on CI i get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Any ideas what could be wrong and why JaVers is not creating tables?

Comment: No idea, looks like a problem with your env, probably an ORA error is thrown from your database, you should check the log from CI

Comment: @BartekWalacik an ORA error (mentioned in question) is raised when Spring is creating Javers bean, not when Javers schould create tables. In logs i get only mentioned in question RuntimeException. The problem appears when I add Javers to second microservice. When only one microservice use Javers everything was OK.

Comment: what is a root cause, why javers tables are not created? You should have logs about successful DDL or ORA error thrown while executing DDL statements